# Delete associated record that isn't yet saved to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So i have an `items` model which can have many `line_items`

some line_items are stored in the database but some are created then edited and/or deleted in memory on the fly without ever being saved back

My question is that once i have created a new line_item for an item in memory how do I then delete it ?

ideally i should be able to narrow down the line_items by it's catagory id then delete it

at the minute I have this code

```
line_items_for_removal = [5,6,7,8] #list of category ids to search through
item = Item.find(1)

    line_items_for_removal.each do |line_item|
      item.line_items.select{|x| x.category_id == line_item nil}.each{|x| item.destroy}
    end
```

This all works fine in selecting the correct records, but it's deleting the persisted record that's the problem.

I've tried both delete and destroy but neither seem to do anything unless the record is persisted

Answer (score 0):

okay so this was resolved by passing in the line_item for deletion as an argument to the delete method as follows

```
 line_items = self.line_items
    line_items_for_removal.each do |item|
      line_items.select{|x| x.category_id = item}.each{|item| line_items.delete(item)}
```